# Xcode NoteApp throws a"unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm unproficient at Objective-c and am trying to build a basic notePad app .
i've finished the first part and am getting this Exception :

```
2014-04-21 15:20:56.983 ToDoList[1261:60b] -[NazorienAddToDoItemViewController
addToDoItemNameField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c4a990
2014-04-21 15:20:57.054 ToDoList[1261:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
xception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'', reason: '-[Nazorie
nAddToDoItemViewController addToDoItemNameField:]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x8c4a990'"
```

this is the class i use for table view of the items.
NazorienToDoItemTableViewController.h class :

```
#import "NazorienToDoListTableViewController.h"
#import "NazorienToDoItem.h"
#import "NazorienAddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface NazorienToDoListTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation NazorienToDoListTableViewController

-(void) loadInitialData {
NazorienToDoItem *item1 = [[NazorienToDoItem alloc] init];
item1.itemName = @"finish this app";
//Adding the to do item to the array "toDoItems"
[self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
NazorienToDoItem *item2 = [[NazorienToDoItem alloc] init];
item2.itemName = @"go to the super market";
[self.toDoItems addObject:item2];

}


-(void)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
NazorienAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
NazorienToDoItem *item = source.addToDoItem;
if(item!=nil)
{
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self loadInitialData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.toDoItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NazorienToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
if(toDoItem.completed){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

//mark completed for selected rows
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {
//deselect the row so that cell is only tapped and not selected for editing
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
//returns the item at the index row of the table
NazorienToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//marks if item is completed or uncompleted
tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
//reload the row
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] 
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

@end
```

this is the class i use for adding items, it holds only 1 text field and cancel and done buttons.
NazorienAddToDoItemViewController.m:

```
#import "NazorienAddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface NazorienAddToDoItemViewController()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end

@implementation NazorienAddToDoItemViewController


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if (sender != self.doneButton) return;
if (self.textField.text.length>0){
    self.addToDoItem = [[NazorienToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.addToDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
    self.addToDoItem.completed = NO;
    //closes the keyboard
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**Edit**
the error happens when i press the "done" or "cancel" buttons in my navigation bar of the NazorienAddToDoListViewAdapter class , and only after i open the keyboard to write a new item name and press either buttons....

Comment: where is `addToDoItemNameField:`

Comment: Post the code where you actually call the `addToDoItemNameField:` method.

Comment: I think that you have included the .m file content for both the .h and .m code blocks in your question - but as the error message says, your class does not implement the method `addToDoItemNameField`  Which class does define this method?

Comment: That what i was looking for since i did not write any method named addToDoItemNameField, and i've changed the code i posted to the other class , at first it was the same class by mistake..

Comment: So you need to write that method...

Comment: As @Paulw11 said, you have to write the `addToDoItemNameField:` method. `unrecognized selector` means that the class you asked to call the method (i.e. selector) does not exist. In your case, that means that your class `NazorienAddToDoItemViewController` does not have the method `addToDoItemNameField:` declared in your `.m` file.

Comment: Thank you all , i tried writing the method, it did not help.
But re setting a new text field in the storyboard fixed the problem.